# Loop through column with only one function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, function, loops

I got a Trend_1 , Trend_2 , Trend_3 ....to Trend_2_3. From that I wan to run a function which return me a signal. The function work well, just I have to do it for many times like repeating the following code but just changing the name.The code are the same, just i have to repeat from df['Signal_1'] to df['Signal_2_3'] manually. Just wonder any other method which can return the function which can read the trend column straight away
[image: My dataframe]

This is my function code which return me a signal_1 to signal_2_3

```
def Signal_processing(df):

signal_1= [None]
for i in range (1,len(df)):
    if df['Trend_1'][i]== 'Up' and df['Trend_1'][i] != df['Trend_1'][i-1]:
        signal_1 += ['Buy']
    elif df['Trend_1'][i] =='Down' and df['Trend_1'][i]!= df['Trend_1'][i-1]:
        signal_1 += ['Sell']
    else :
        signal_1 += [None]

df['Signal_1'] = signal_1 

index=[]
bs=[]
for i in range (len(df)):
    if df['Signal_1'][i] == 'Buy' or df['Signal_1'][i] == 'Sell':
        bs.append(df['Signal_1'][i])
        index.append(i)

for i in range (1,len(bs)):
    if bs[i] == bs[i-1]:
        df['Signal_1'][index[i]]='None'
```

Code like this will be repeating 7 times but just the name are different.

```
signal_7=[None]
for i in range (1,len(df)):
    if df['Trend_2_3'][i]=='Up' and df['Trend_2_3'][i]!= df['Trend_2_3'][i-1] :
        signal_7 += ['Buy']
    elif df['Trend_2_3'][i] == 'Down' and df['Trend_2_3'][i]!= df['Trend_2_3'] [i-1]:
        signal_7 += ['Sell']
    else:
        signal_7 += [None]
df['Signal_2_3'] = signal_7   

    index=[]
bs=[]
for i in range (len(df)):
    if df['Signal_2_3'][i] == 'Buy' or df['Signal_2_3'][i] == 'Sell':
        bs.append(df['Signal_2_3'][i])
        index.append(i)

for i in range (1,len(bs)):
    if bs[i] == bs[i-1]:
        df['Signal_2_3'][index[i]]='None'              

return df
```

Comment: You say "Code like this will be repeating 7 times but just the name are different.", do you mean 'Trend_1' ... etc? If so, have you considered putting that code in a function and adding a parameter 'name'?

Comment: That is mean I'm manually repeating the code but just the df['Trend_1'] will be changed to df['Trend_2'], df['Trend_3'] etc. Code are the same except  df['Trend_1'] will be repeating from  df['Trend_1'] to  df['Trend_7']

Comment: Is `df` a pandas dataframe?  Whatever `df` is, most data objects allow you to get a list of columns for the purpose of iterating through them without knowing the column names.  The currently accepted answer will work, but if you add a new column or remove an existing one, your code will break.  If you iterate through the columns dynamically, it wont.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just change the function call from

```
def Signal_processing(df):
    # do some stuff for all trends
```

to

```
def Signal_processing(df):
    sub_signal_processing(df,"1")
    sub_signal_processing(df,"2")
    sub_signal_processing(df,"2_3")
    #etc

def sub_signal_processing(df, no):
    # do some stuff for a specific trend specified by the string 'no'
    # If no = "7", then Trend_7 will be processed to Signal_7,
    # If no = "2_3", then Trend_2_3 will be processed to Signal_2_3 etc.
```

and then change every instance for e.g. Trend_2_3 and Signal_2_3 in the following way:

```
# Former specific call
df['Trend_2_3']
df['Signal_2_3']
# The same call if no = "2_3"
df['Trend_%s' % no]
df['Signal_%s' % no]
```

where `no` is a string. You would then need to move everything from Signal_processing that processes e.g. Trend_1 down into sub_signal_processing and replace _1 with the generalised version as specified above. The following code should do what you want:

```
def Signal_processing(df):
    # Could add more here
    for no in ("1", "2", "3", "1_2_3", "1_2", "1_3", "2_3"):
        sub_signal_processing(df, no)

def sub_signal_processing(df, no):
    signal= [None]
    for i in range (1,len(df)):
        if df['Trend_%s' % no][i]== 'Up' and df['Trend_%s' % no][i] != df['Trend_%s' % no][i-1]:
            signal += ['Buy']
        elif df['Trend_%s' % no][i] =='Down' and df['Trend_%s' % no][i]!= df['Trend_%s' % no][i-1]:
            signal += ['Sell']
        else :
            signal += [None]

    df['Signal_%s' % no] = signal

    index=[]
    bs=[]
    for i in range (len(df)):
        if df['Signal_%s' % no][i] == 'Buy' or df['Signal_%s' % no][i] == 'Sell':
            bs.append(df['Signal_%s' % no][i])
            index.append(i)

    for i in range (1,len(bs)):
        if bs[i] == bs[i-1]:
            df['Signal_%s' % no][index[i]]='None'
```

Comment: # do some stuff for a specific trend specified by the string 'no' <-  i dont get it this part. I can change my df name to df['Signal_7'] or something else, not necessary df['Signal_2_3']

Comment: how can i edit or just change something from my original code and put it under sub_signal_processing?

Comment: It give a big helps to me! thanks alot man! Truly appreciated